# Custom allocation using boost singleton_pool slower than default

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-pool, boost-pool

I wrote custom operator new and operator delete for the class MyOrder. I am allocating memory using boost::singleton pool. Here is the program testing the performance,

```
#include <boost/pool/singleton_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/progress.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <vector>


class MyOrder{
    std::vector<int> v1_;
    std::vector<double> v2_;

    std::string s1_;
    std::string s2_;

public:
    MyOrder(std::string s1, std::string s2): s1_(s1), s2_(s2) {}

    ~MyOrder(){}

    static void * operator new(size_t size); 
    static void operator delete(void * rawMemory) throw();
};

struct MyOrderTag{};
typedef boost::singleton_pool<MyOrderTag, sizeof(MyOrder)> MyOrderPool; 

void* MyOrder:: operator new(size_t size)
{
    if (size != sizeof(MyOrder)) 
        return ::operator new(size);

    while(true){
        void * ptr = MyOrderPool::malloc();
        if (ptr != NULL) return ptr;

        std::new_handler globalNewHandler = std::set_new_handler(0);
        std::set_new_handler(globalNewHandler);

        if(globalNewHandler)  globalNewHandler();
        else throw std::bad_alloc();

    }
}

void MyOrder::operator delete(void * rawMemory) throw()
{
    if(rawMemory == 0) return; 
    MyOrderPool::free(rawMemory);
}

int main()
{
    MyOrder* mo = NULL; 
    std::vector<MyOrder*> v;
    v.reserve(100000);

    boost::progress_timer howlong;
    for(int i = 0; i< 100000; ++i)
    {
        mo = new MyOrder("Sanket", "Sharma");
        v.push_back(mo);
    }

    for (std::vector<MyOrder*>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        delete *it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above program using -O2 flag and ran on my Macbook with 2.26 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and it took 0.16 seconds. Then I commented off the lines where I have declared and defined the custom operator new and operator delete, recompiled with -O2 flags and ran on the same machine it took 0.13 seconds.

Allocating and deallocating memory using singleton_pool for objects of same size should speed it up. Why is it making it slow? Or is the overhead of creating a pool nullifying the performance benefit gained in this small program?

Update:

I replaced the two std::string variables with an int and a double and this time ran the two programs with 100000000 (ie 1000 times before) iterations each on a 3.0 GHZ AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 945 Processor. The one using custom memory allocation takes 3.2 seconds while the one using default memory allocation takes 8.26 seconds. So this time custom memory allocation wins.

Comment: Since you're taking the trouble to call *one* new handler, you should probably write a loop to try *all* new handlers.

Comment: Your test is including the allocations by `std::string` which aren't governed by your custom allocator, so any results you get are misleading _at best_.

Comment: @Chad I replaced std::string by a double and an int. This time I am iterating them 10000000 times. The results are 1.95s for default vs 2.29s for custom. Still allocation/deallocation using pool is slower.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am following the approach mentioned in Effective C++. I am not sure what you mean when you say "all new handlers". Please educate me about it.

Comment: @sanket: There's an example implementation as a note in the C++ standard document itself. Basically, a new hander can set a new new handler, so you need to loop until you get a null pointer. If you want a full description, maybe post a separate question, though it's not terribly important.

Comment: See 18.6.1/4 for a description of the default behaviour of `::operator new`.

Answer (score 5):

I think your numbers are meaningless. If you only checked the runtime once, and you found `0.13` vs `0.16` seconds than that is entirely meaningless, and dominated by overhead.

You must run the snippet you want to test thousands of times and then compare the data to rule out overhead.

No really, that `0.03` seconds difference can easily be explained by your process getting switched out, etc.